# react native --how to split react native's jsbundle into separate files

Tags: react-native

I use curl `http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle\?dev\=0&minify\=1 -o main.jsbundle` to generate a document, but it is about 500k+. How can I make it smaller?

Answer (score 0):

If you can verify it's already minified there's no straightforward way to make it smaller but I believe the team behind the React Native Packager is planning a feature called bundle splitting which should allow you to only require a subset of `react-native`.